# macbookPro Slows down to half of its processing power

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, osx-mountain-lion, macbook-pro

I have a macbook pro 2010 made, core2duo, 4 gb ram and i m running Mountain Lion on it.

before few days I was playing 8 ball pool on browser suddenly my system was crashed and shut him self down.

Now the problem is

1. I can not start the system by pressing & releasing a start button, i have to hold the start key until the indicator light starts blinking and then its starts.
2. My system slows down to half of its processing power. hardly i can open 2 applications.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a harware issue, possibly related to heat management. Check that the fans are working and that there is no dust or obstruction in the case. You might have to replace the CPU.

Comment: it is clean and Fans are working fine rather they are more loud now after that problem. Replace :(

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, reset the internal controller (PRAM) - Switch on, quickly hold down cmd-option-p-r all at once - keep holding down until hear the second chime. Try using the system again.

If that does not work ....

Get an external USB drive of over 100gb, re-install the OS onto the USB drive by holding down ALT at switch on and selecting the recovery partition. When going through the installation process make sure you select the USB drive for install location, and that the USB drive is mac formatted.

Once that is done, boot system again holding down ALT and then select the USB drive to boot from - See if you can open and use normally. If you can then only a re-install of OSX is needed.

Unfortunately - the processor cannot be replaced very easily at all - but purchase an air-duster and give it a good blast in the area behind the hinge.

Comment: i already reinstalled the OS, no change. i will do the air duster thing :)